# Set breakpoint at specific line with gdb

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, breakpoints, disassembly

I have two files:

`bomb.c` and `bomb` (executable). In the `.c` file there are calls to the `bomb` file. I cannot see the inside of the bomb file though, only, of course, the disassembly.

I'm currently running on Linux, and I'm trying to set some breakpoints to better understand the inside of the bomb file.

I do:

```
gdb bomb
b 0x0000000000401061
```

But it doesn't work, since I get the error:

```
Function "0x0000000000401061" not defined.
```

From the disassembly of `bomb` I was able to recognize some function, and if I do:

```
b [function name]
```

the breakpoint is set.

I wish to set it into a specific line, which is not a function.
How can I do that?

Comment: Why can you only see the disassembly?  Can you not compile with debug symbols?

Comment: `gdb -g bomb.c -o bomb; gdb bomb;`  Inside gdb, execute `break bomb.c:45` to set a break point at line 45.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set breakpoint at specific line with gdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65410033/set-breakpoint-at-specific-line-with-gdb)

Comment: @WilliamPursell if I write that command I get:
`unrecognized option -g`

Comment: @ucei Sorry, that is supposed to be `gcc -g bomb.c -o bomb`.  You need to compile with debug symbols

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me:

```
b *0x401061
```

Instead of:

```
b 0x0000000000401061
```